# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT when trying to access Google Classroom course announcements

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

My user account can use the Google Classroom web UI to see all the announcements for a given course. Trying to pull them programmatically using the Google Classroom API.

I've set up an app with Oauth consent screen covering (for test purposes) **ALL** the scopes listed under the Google Classroom API, and can run the consent flow with my user account to get an access token.

I can successfully GET course details by curl'ing `https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/<my course ID>` using the access token obtained from the oauth flow. However, when I GET `https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/<my course ID>/announcements` with the same token, I get the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "google.classroom.v1.Work.ListAnnouncements",
                    "service": "classroom.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Behaviour is same in using both client libraries as well as raw REST calls.

Am I missing an auth scope (I switched them all on), am I just not allowed to do this since I'm not the course owner, or am I doing something else wrong? Advice please!

Comment: Please edit your question and include a list of the scopes that you are requesting.

Comment: please include [example]

Answer (score 0):

You apear to be using the [courses.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get) method

In order to access this method your application needs to be authorized with one of the following scopes.

[image]

You also appear to be using the [courses.announcements.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list) method

This method requires that your application be authorized with one of the following scopes.

[image]

The error message `"Request had insufficient authentication scopes."` means exactly what it says. The access token you are using was not authorized with one of the scopes needed for the courses.announcements.list endpoint there for you can not use it.

You need to delete the access token you have now and request authorization of the user using the proper scope for this method.  Always make sure to delete your old token.  When changing scopes in code your app does not always request authorization again if you just change the scopes in the code. You need to force it to request authorization again.

## All the scopes

you should not be requesting all of the scopes of the user only the scopes that you need. If you only need readonly access make sure not to request write.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As a test, I reduced the scopes to those indicated above (classroom.courses.readonly, classroom.announcements.readonly). No change in the result. 
I have been explicitly rotating the token for every test so that wouldn't appear to explain it either.

Comment: I'm getting somewhere - when I GET `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo` to inspect my access token I get
````{
    "issued_to": "730806407707-2vd5cbbtq3p0s40ts3d0ibgdkds7gvhq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "audience": "730806407707-2vd5cbbtq3p0s40ts3d0ibgdkds7gvhq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
    "expires_in": 3115,
    "access_type": "offline"
}````

So the access token actually DOESN'T have the classroom.announcements scope, even though I configured it in the oauth consent screen console page.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that my code explicitly defines the scopes when configuring the client that then builds the oauth request URL:

```
config, err = google.ConfigFromJSON(b, classroom.ClassroomCoursesReadonlyScope)
```

Changed to

```
config, err = google.ConfigFromJSON(b, classroom.ClassroomCoursesReadonlyScope, **classroom.ClassroomAnnouncementsReadonlyScope**)
```

and it works fine.